# Is Random Forest (in python) a boosting algorithm?

Tags: python, random-forest, xgboost, gradient-descent, boosting

I'm looking for the main differences between random forest and gradient boosting and I don't understand whether random forest uses boosting techniques and if not, why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.

Difference is subtle, but important - its Bagging ( Bootstrap aggregating ) algorhitm. resampling in [Random Forrest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) is random, while in [Boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_%28machine_learning%29) is not.

Confusion might come from fact, that [AdaBoost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) ( boosting algorhitm ) can be using RF after few optimisation iterations.